# Copy and Swap Idiom and Iterators

Tags: c++, iterator

I have been writing a doubly linked list with nested iterators. When I was working on copy constructor and operator= overloading, I came across Copy-swap-idiom. But from what I realize, it uses the RULE OF THREE (and a Half, if you want). But  iterators don't have a destructor, because the "node" they point to isn't their "property", its doubly lists.

This is a university assignment and I am asked to write a copy constructor and operator no matter what the case, wether it's the same as implicit definition or not.

My question is does copy-swap-idiom always need to have a destuctor? If so in Iterators case, would this work or should I use normal "dirty" assignment? Below is relevant part of my iterator class:

```
template<class T>
class List<T>::ForwardIterator {
private:
    Node<T> *current;

public:
    ForwardIterator(Node<T> *curr = nullptr) : current(curr) {}
    ForwardIterator(const ForwardIterator& right) : current(right.current) {}
...
...
```

Above part shows the constructors and private data of iterator. Below part shows it's assignment and swap function.

```
friend void swap(ForwardIterator& first, ForwardIterator& second) {
    using std::swap;
    swap(first.current, second.current);
}

ForwardIterator& operator=(ForwardIterator right) {
    swap(*this, right);
    return *this;
}
```

This is my implementation, and I wanted to know is it wise to use here? (My iterator doesn't have a destructor, hence my question).

Comment: you dont need `ForwardIterator(const ForwardIterator& right)`, it will be implicitly declared by the compiler. Which means you don't need to care about the rule of three (of 5 actually), which comes for free in your case.

Comment: @UmNyobe Yep, that is the case, but I forgot to mention(updating post now), that since this a university assignment, I am asked to write a copy constructor no matter what the case.

Comment: @OsamaAsifCInfinitum I don't suppose `YouClass(YourClass const&) = default;` counts as writing your own?

Comment: @WhozCraig I doubt they will accept that, their mindset is way too weird, trust me I don't like writing things that don't need to be written, but what can you do...

Comment: @OsamaAsifCInfinitum Something to leave in the course comments, I suppose. Good luck with that.

Comment: @WhozCraig haha will do, let's hope they improve their standard

Answer (score 2):

What you have is correct and will work, but it is not needed.

Since your iterator isn't responsible for the node it is holding a pointer to it is fine to have a do nothing destuctor.  Because you have a do nothing destructor you don't need to do anything special for any of the copy/move constructors or copy/move assignment operators.  This means you don't need to define any of them and you can follow the rule of zero.

Remember, you only need to implement the rule of 3/rule of 5 when your class is actually responsible for acquiring and releasing a resource.  If all you are doing is dealing with POD/RAII types then the compiler defaults will "do the right thing".

Comment: I agree with you, but keeping in mind it's a university assignment, which I have added in the question, they have asked to write it anyway. So keeping this in mind, do you think my approach of copy-swap-idiom is right? And do iterators in general ever need to have a destructor? Thanks!

Comment: @OsamaAsifCInfinitum Your copy and swap is fine.  Generally iterators don't need destructors is all they do is point to an element.